# Kurento Media server 6.6 and one 2 one application behind Nat

Tags: webrtc, nat, kurento

I am running KMS server and kurento one to one call behind Nat. I can only connect my call when I am under VPN. Outside Vpn I am not able to connect the call.

Comment: You need to setup STUN and TURN server to make it work. I am also facing some issue, not sure how to set it up though on client, but in case of kurento media server you need to specify it inside /etc/kurento/module/kurento/WebRtcEndpoint

Comment: http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html here the place where you could find how to configure STUN/TURN in Kurento.

Comment: @BilboBaggins I have resolved the issue. We need to set configuration when making web rtc peer connection.

Comment: I have resolved the issue to some extent, i..e it works on Open network (i.e. network without firewall) but when I add a TURN server I can't receive my call on the other side it self. I am not sure what goes wrong over there. Can you please share your configuration (not only client side config but also how did you manage it to make it work behind a firewall)  here in the answers for TURN ? Thanks :)

Comment: You can check the first answer. Pass configuration in options for making peer connection. Use stun server configuration as you can see in the answer and also in /etc/kurento/module/kurento/WebRtcEndpoint, set to use same stun server. It works in both situations for inside or outside firewall.

Comment: ok, thank you :)  but in my case I am facing some weird issues while I put my app inside firewalled network. basically the call doesn't work and I configured TURN then it stopped receiving of call on other peer's page.

Comment: first check using public stun server.

Answer (score -1):

```
let options = {
    localVideo: video,
    mediaConstraints: constraints,
    onicecandidate: localParticipant.onIceCandidate.bind(localParticipant),
    configuration : { iceServers : [
               {"url":"stun:74.125.200.127:19302"},
               ] } 
};

localParticipant.rtcPeer = new kurentoUtils.WebRtcPeer.WebRtcPeerSendonly(options, function(error) {
    if (error) {
        return console.error(error);
    }

    localVideoCurrentId = sessionId;

    localVideo = document.getElementById('local_video');
    localVideo.src = localParticipant.rtcPeer.localVideo.src;
    localVideo.muted = true;

    this.generateOffer(localParticipant.offerToReceiveVideo.bind(localParticipant));
});
```

The stun server here is the ip for this domain stun.l.google.com.